# .NET Core - Why should I use View Components over Blazor Components integrated in MVC App or Razor Pages

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor

In our new project we use View Compoments in our existing MVC App for separated and reusable components. Lately Blazor has taken some serious steps forward. We recognized that it's much more convenient using Blazor Components for like asynchronous tasks. For example adding an item to a cart:

### View Component (old approach):

In a View Component we need to make an AJAX - POST to add a position and then reload the cart view component via an AJAX - GET request.

### Razor component (new approach)

official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/integrate-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1

In a Razor component we simply call the underlying @code - method to add a position and can invoke an event which rerenders the cart view component. So we can go without JavaScript at all. Below a working example in my MVC app:

#### ProductList.razor

```
<div>
@foreach (var c in products)
{
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="@c.ImageURL" class="img-fluid p-3" alt="@c.Description ">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 d-flex">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold mr-auto">@c.Title</span>
                    <span class="ml-auto">@c.Number</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btnAddToCart" @onclick="(() => addposition(c.ID))"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

#### ProductList.razor.cs

Separated the code, but works the same as when I put it in "@Code()" on my razor component (inherits vom ComponentBase)

```
public partial class ProductList : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject] Business.Cart cart { get; set; }
    [Inject] Business.Product product { get; set; }

    protected List<ListProduct> products = new List<ListProduct>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        List<ListProduct> temp = await product.GetProductList(new GetProductListRequest { CategoryURL = UrlDesc });
        products = temp;
    }

    protected async Task addposition(int artid)
    {
        CartAddPositionResponse resp = await cart.AddPosition(new CartAddPositionRequest { ProductID = artid });
        cart.CallRequestRefresh();
    }
}
```

#### Catalog.cshtml (MVC View)

```
<component type="typeof(ProductList)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" param-urlDesc="@Model.urlDesc"/>
```

### This leads to the following question:

Are there any reasons to use View Components at all, if I just can use Blazor Components, which provide the advantage of calling asynchronous methods directly and can be reused multiple times anywhere in the project? Are there and disadvantages?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you're not supposed to use view components in Blazor at all.

Comment: is Blazor ready for production use?

Comment: @KieranDevlin I use view components / blazor components in a MVC app, not in a Blazor app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/integrate-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @vasily.sib yes, server side blazor is ready for producion use with .net Core 3.1

Comment: @vasily.sib to be exact, server side Blazor is supported since .net core 3.0. Since .net 3.1 it has LTS support. Blazor webassembly is scheduled for release in march of this year

Answer (score 0):

A major functionality of the View Component is that it renders a chunk instead of the whole response. This can be used to render View along with data e.g. Login/Logout Panel across all Views, Navigation Bar, recent updates in data etc. View Components allows you to run asynchronous operations on them,too.